# How to Configure a Server with two NIC

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

[image]

I'm reformulating the question, once the previous provoked a little confusion.

I didn't find a way to subnet `172.16.1.0/26` between two interfaces. MY thought was to set device's gateway to the next device.

Ex:

```
R3 - 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.192
Server Fa0/0 - 172.16.1.2 255.255.255.192 ; 172.16.1.1
Server Fa0/1 - 172.16.1.3 255.255.255.192 ; 172.16.1.2
```

Triggered it : **PT uses 1st port as the default port to forward traffic to the outside network. The 2nd port is only for forwarding traffic within the subnet. Configuring default gateway on 2nd port is insignificant.**

How to subnet my network for what all traffic can pass and be filtered?

Comment: You need to change the addresses of the PCs or your router.  Which is easier for you?  The server will have only ONE default gateway address.

Comment: Both ways are easier. But I don't understand so well, Which Server's Interface should keep only one default gateway? inbound or outbound ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the server Fa0 to 172.16.1.66 255.255.255.192  The default gateway is 172.16.1.65.

Fa1 has the original address 172.16.1.3 255.255.255.192. No default gateway.

Change the router interface fa0/0 to 172.16.1.65 255.255.255.192

You will also need a static route on the router:

```
ip route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.192 172.16.1.66
```

Comment: Ok, My Router: `172.16.1.1 255.255.255.192` ; Server Fa0/0 `172.16.1.2 255.255.255.192 - GT `172.16.1.1` ; How is the host configuration? Server Fa0/1 doesn't exists configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry.  I corrected the answer

Comment: Done! The packet never arrive in Fa1, what Should I do? If I use another address trigger that message

Comment: Where is the packet from, and where is it going?

Comment: From PC7 to Router

Comment: What is the default gateway of that PC?  It should be the address of Fa1.

Comment: Yes, but You didn't write how to configure Fa1, Both interfaces You wrote were Fa0, I didn't understand so well

Comment: I corrected it.  Sorry for all the errors.