# When server has 2 NIC, device from one network can't ping another

Tags: ping, packet-tracer, networking

I've successfully completed the network design and everything worked just fine until I tried to ping the computer on the edge. Well, Master server "sees" the connections on both lines, but when I try to access Slave from the router or vice versa, ping doesn't reach the destination.

Here I provide the screenshot of the problematic part:

[image]

In real world the computer is an industrial controller which can be accessed from a computer via another controller. 
The ip-plan is as follows:

[image]

Mask is 255.255.255.0 for all!

Routing configuration:

[image]

> 192.168.1.66 appeared during multiple experiments and doesn't have any influence on the result. For this entry I tried to rollback my network to it's permanent state.

I checked out [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20819/how-to-configure-a-server-with-two-nic) thread, but when I tried to assign the proposed IP-addresses, got an error that this range is used on another port. I didn't manage to find any other similar issues online.

So how can I access the "Slave" from the "Router"?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. Routers route between networks.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you! I considered it being an enterprise network was a sufficient condition to be here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two networks to communicate you need a **router** in between.

If the Master server isn't acting as a router, it isn't forwarding between networks, and the networks can't communicate.

So, you either need to configure Master to route (host configurations are off-topic on NE) or connect Slave to the router directly.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! That's exactly what I suspected but didn't know for sure. But at least I have a clue that it is possible to configure host this way.